# Default variables for iteratively created spinboxes in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am try to set default values for some spinboxes that I am creating iteratively. I have searched this topic pretty extensively and found two options. One option uses d=default sb.delete(0, "end") with sb.insert(0, d) and the other uses a StringVar() to set the default with textvariable. Neither of these options seem to work, and the StringVar() option links all of the values so that when I change one value it changes them all.

```
def skills(self):
        self.genGet = {}
        i=0
        for key in Skills.genList:
            self.var1 = tk.IntVar()
            ttk.Label(self.frame, text=key).grid(column=0, row=i, sticky='W')
            sbGen = tk.Spinbox(self.frame, from_=0, to=5, width=3)
            sbGen.grid(column=1, row=i, sticky='W', pady=5, padx=5)
            self.genGet[key] = (sbGen, self.var1)
            i+=1
```

This is my code that runs fine and creates the expected result except for the default value.

edit -- Skills() is a class that just contains a few dicts.

Comment: would you prefer an answer with or without using an `IntVar`?

Comment: I feel like a total loser. I figured this out just a minute after posting this after quite a while of trying to figure it out. Turns out you have to put the delete and inserts after Spinbox AND grid

Comment: They don't have to be after `grid`, they just have to be after you create the widget.

Comment: Good point, I moved the insert and delete to confirm and it still works. Must have been some typo that didn't give cause an error.

Comment: As a side note: do you know about `enumerate`? `for i, key in enumerate(Skills.getList):`.

Comment: yes, I know about `enumerate`. It's a documented part of python. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: does enumerate just make the first variable increase each iteration? Could i do i=8 for i, key in enumerate(skills.genList): ?

Comment: Did you read the doc that Bryan Oakley linked? It notes that the `enumerate` function has a `start` argument which makes it start counting at a certain value.